# Cant connect to server using Socket.IO Objective-C ios

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO-Client-Swift' -15.2.0' to implement my project in Objective-C. Created Singleton class and my code is like , Decalred Property in .h file

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) SocketManager *soManager;
@property(strong, nonatomic) SocketIOClient *soClient;
```

in .m File

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:socketURL];
self.soManager = [[SocketManager alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{
    @"log" : @YES, @"compress": @YES
}];

self.soClient = [self.soManager defaultSocket];

[self.soClient on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
   NSLog(@"event connect");
}];

[self.soClient on:@"connected" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
   NSLog(@"event connected");
}];

[self.soClient on:@"error" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
   NSLog(@"ERROR with socket %@", data);
}];

[self.soClient connect];
```

Output:

```
2021-03-16 17:39:48.037142+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connectedDevice
2021-03-16 17:39:48.037632+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2021-03-16 17:39:48.037907+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connected
2021-03-16 17:39:48.038152+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: error
2021-03-16 17:39:48.038380+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: some message
2021-03-16 17:39:48.038673+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2021-03-16 17:39:48.038960+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] Receive Event SocketAnyEvent: Event: statusChange items: Optional([connecting, 2])
2021-03-16 17:39:48.039300+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2021-03-16 17:39:48.040039+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2021-03-16 17:39:48.046416+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2021-03-16 17:39:48.047298+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952738] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://13.126.210.13:3000
2021-03-16 17:39:48.047541+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952738] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2021-03-16 17:39:48.048076+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952738] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://13.126.210.13:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
2021-03-16 17:39:48.068964+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] ERROR SocketManager: Error
2021-03-16 17:39:48.069861+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Error"]
2021-03-16 17:39:48.070019+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] Receive Event SocketAnyEvent: Event: error items: Optional(["Error"])
2021-03-16 17:39:48.070234+0530 Draiwil[61406:6952467] ERROR with socket (
    Error
)

Socket Url : http://13.126.210.13:3000
```

Not able to connect Server, can you please help?

Comment: Show output and ```socketURL```?

Comment: yes i've edited output and socket url in my question .. pls check

Comment: Note ```3000``` in code and ```300``` in URL but I think this is not the problem. Seems to be working up until ```http://13.126.210.13:3000``` and breaking with ```Doing polling GET http://13.126.210.13:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1``` - are you sure the server is responding as you expect to that? Maybe test it in e.g. postman?

Comment: yes "300" is my typing mistake here actual is "3000" as well as in code also there is "3000". and Yes server is responding in android at a time. here we got problem

Comment: Draiwil[61513:6975770] ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
 Draiwil[61513:6975770] ERROR SocketEngine: Error
 Draiwil[61513:6975723] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released

Comment: http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/#eyJsaXN0ZW4iOlsibWVzc2FnZSIsInNvY2tldGlvLWNsaWVudCJdLCJlbWl0IjpbInNvY2tldGlvLWNsaWVudCIsInNvY2tldGlvLWNsaWVudC1hY2siXSwiY29uZmlnIjoie1wicGF0aFwiOiBcIi9zb2NrZXQuaW9cIiwgXCJmb3JjZU5ld1wiOiB0cnVlLCBcInJlY29ubmVjdGlvbkF0dGVtcHRzXCI6IDMsIFwidGltZW91dFwiOiAyMDAwfSJ9.      checked in this link which check online socket.io connection .. here also its connects

Comment: Hi - is difficult with just this info to find the problem, but if the server works then it is probably on the client side. Maybe you need to connect securely to get it to work or at least config your app to connect to that server using http?

Comment: is my object declaration and all are correct in code? is there any glitch you found in code?

Comment: This portion looks fine. The problem seems to start when you start polling, and since you confirm that the server is working, maybe the client is the problem. Maybe the client is not responding correctly to the polling, which is not shown here.